# Extract Water heads in MODFLOW-NWT using FloPy

Tags: python, numpy, flopy

I am using MODFLOW-NWT using FloPy to model groundwater system. I am aiming to extract the water heads for each kper (stress period). I used this code (below) to read all heads,but not sure how to save each heads for each period and calculate the mean value as a function of space.

```
hds_file = "hist.bhd"
hds = bf.HeadFile(hds_file,text='head', precision='single')
print(hds)

for k in range(348):
    kper = k
    times = hds.get_times()
    head = hds.get_data(totim=times[k])   

    print(head)
```

I am expecting to save the heads for each stress period and how to calculate the average as a fuction of space for each model node (cell).

Comment: When you print `head`, what does it show?

Comment: array like this, all stress periods:
[[[1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
  ...
  [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]]]
[[[1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
  ...
  [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]]]
[[[1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
  ...
  [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]

Comment: Is that a 3D array? Do you know what each dimension represents?

Comment: Yes, it is, each array 154 rows*  110 columns

Comment: But what do they represent?

Comment: It's water levels across modflow model. Each cell has unique value.